# How to remove inline scripts and styles from WordPress (Yoast SEO, emojis)?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I want to remove most css and scripts added by Yoast SEO plugin to my wordpress page. How can I trace which function in Yoast SEO plugin adds which code so that I can try to remove it. I am a noob, so I would appreciate if you could show also a complete code to put to my functions.php to remove for instance this:

a)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window._wpemojiSettings = ...
```

b)

```
<script src="http://dev.a2b.lv/wp-includes/js/wp-emoji-release.min.js?ver=4.8.2" type="text/javascript" defer=""></script>
```

c)

```
<style type="text/css">
img.wp-smiley,
img.emoji {
display: inline !important;
...
}
</style>
```

d)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" id="admin-bar-css" href="http://dev.a2b.lv/wp-includes/css/admin-bar.min.css?ver=4.8.2" type="text/css" media="all">
```

I hope from there I will figure out how to remove the rest.

Answer (score 1):

All of your a, b, c, d problems are not relate to Yoast SEO plugin. It's come from WordPress core.

**abc**) Add this code to the end of your `functions.php` file of your current theme:

```
function disable_emojis() {
    remove_action( 'wp_head', 'print_emoji_detection_script', 7 );
    remove_action( 'admin_print_scripts', 'print_emoji_detection_script' );
    remove_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );
    remove_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'print_emoji_styles' );   
    remove_filter( 'the_content_feed', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );
    remove_filter( 'comment_text_rss', 'wp_staticize_emoji' );     
    remove_filter( 'wp_mail', 'wp_staticize_emoji_for_email' );
    add_filter( 'tiny_mce_plugins', 'disable_emojis_tinymce' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'disable_emojis' );

function disable_emojis_tinymce( $plugins ) {
    if ( is_array( $plugins ) ) {
        return array_diff( $plugins, array( 'wpemoji' ) );
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

**d**) Logout from your WordPress page will do the job. That means your normal visitor will not have to load admin-bar.css...

Comment: Ahn, thank you very much! Your solution works perfecty. Could you also share how did you find out what to put in remove_filter and add_filter functions parameters. There are some other things I want to remove.